# Word 2016 - How to make collapsible section that's not visible in the navigation pane?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2016

I have a docx file, and I would like to have some sections with collapsible parts.
I can make it with *Styles*. I have to use a custom Style. At *Modify Style*->*Format*->*Paragraph* I have to use Level 1-9 at *Outline Level*.

Then I can collapse the section with this header style.
As descriped here: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Collapse-or-expand-parts-of-a-document-701786e0-95e2-40bf-bfe5-f0233cd3520c

I would like to add document instructions in these collapsible text.
My problem is that if I use this method to create collapsible text, then these sections will be visible in the Navigation pane.

The navigation pane checks the *Outline Level* of a heading to choose what to show in this sidebar. 
The same Outline Level is used for making the text collapsible.

But if there are 50 chapters in the document, and every chapter have a document instruction text in it, then there will be 50 extra item in the Navigation pane.
That makes the Nav. pane hardly usable.

I tried to use "Outline level 9" for the instruction, and then I tried to hide heading levels higher then 4 in the Navigation pane, but it does not work...
If there is an instruction text beneath a Level 2 heading, then the Navigation Pane will display the instruction section as a new header, even if the instruction header style is in *Outline level 9* + I modified the Pane to show only Level 4 headers...

Do you know any solution to have a separate collapsible section in a Word document without extra header in the Navigation bar?

Thanks in advance ;)

.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "the feature that collapse a section and will not be visible in the navigation pane is not yet available in Word"

See this answer for details:
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_winother/word-2016-how-to-make-collapsible-section-thats/90946c19-d7b4-409c-a5e8-32836aa6d487?tm=1493207351687&rtAction=1493294493824